# Simple function problem, local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function

I'm very new to coding and am having trouble with functions. What is wrong with this and how can I do this properly?

```
x = 0
def function():
    x = x + 1
    return(x)
x = 2
x = function()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify (bind) a variable *anywhere* in a function, it's considered to be local *everywhere* in that function unless explicitly declared `global` or `nonlocal`<sup>(a)</sup>. This is covered by the [Python execution model](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/executionmodel.html):

> If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block, unless ...

In other words, what you have is effectively:

```
x = 0
def function():
    local_x = local_x + 1 # use of unitialised local_x
    return(local_x)
```

That means you need something like:

```
x = 0
def function():
    global x
    x = x + 1 # use of initialised x
    return(x)
```

---

However, keep in mind that global variables are mostly the *wrong* way to do things. They're probably okay for small programs but can become a nightmare when you get to a certain complexity level.

One method to do this is to just pass in the variable and pass back the modified value, re-assigning it in the caller:

```
def function(value):
    return value + 1

def caller():
    non_global_x = function(non_global_x)
```

Note that `non_global_x` *may* still be a global in that case but it can be also any other suitable variable, such as the member of an object.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The difference between these two is that `global` means global, meaning it will be available everywhere. Non-local variables simply refer to ones somewhere up the hierarchy, but you may find them before you get to global scope (often used in nested functions).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed answer, but would you mind giving me an example of an alternative to global variables, but still using functions?

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to this if you want to assign variable located outside the function:

```
def function():
    global x
    x = x + 1
    return x
```